# Opening or creating UIManagedDocument gives weird output

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimanageddocument

Basically, I am having a problem with opening or creating an `UIManagedDocument`. I set up the code along with print statements in it. My code is below:

```
// Creates managed document when accessed for the first time
- (UIManagedDocument *)document
{
    if (!_document) {
        // Finds the url for document
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:(NSUserDomainMask)] firstObject];
        NSString *documentName = @"FlickrPhotoDatabase";
        NSURL *documentURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
        _document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];
    }
    return _document;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"start launch");
    // Checks to see if document can be created
    if ([self createUIManagedDocument]) {
        NSLog(@"document created");
        if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
            self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
            NSLog(@"document starts fetching flickr");
            [self fetchFlickrPhotos];
        }
        NSLog(@"End of document state");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error, could not open or create an UIManagedDocument.");
    }

    return YES;
}

// Tries to create or open UIManagedDocument and returns the result
- (BOOL)createUIManagedDocument
{
    __block BOOL successful = false;
    NSLog(@"In createUIManagedDocument");
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[self.document fileURL] path]]) {
        [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"file exists at path %hhd", success);
            successful = success;
        }];
    }
    else {
        [self.document saveToURL:[self.document fileURL]
                forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
               completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                   NSLog(@"File created at path %hhd", success);
                   successful = success;
               }];
    }

    return successful;
}
```

The weird thing is that the execution of the code should print out (using worst case scenario):

- start launch
- in `createUIManagedDocument`
- error could not open or create an `UIManagedObject`

However, my output shows:

- start launch
- in `createUIManagedDocument`
- error could not open or create an `UIManagedObject`
- file created at path 1

What I don't understand is how the message "file created at path 1" gets printed after the execution of the method. I am pretty sure that solving this would fix my problem to create a `UIManagedDocument`.

Comment: The message gets logged because it's in the completion handler?

Comment: Does that mean the statement gets executed on a different thread and does not get outputted until its completed?

Comment: Yeah, that's the case. It'd obviously be executed every time you run this code, whether the method fails or succeeds.

Comment: That makes so much sense on why my code isn't working. Thanks.